# Create new column with for cycle and receiving an error

Tags: python, pandas

I am defining a function on python basically what it does is generate a new column on the DataFrame on which the values are the difference of the values of another column in the DataFrame.

Maybe the code might do my explanation a little bit less confusing:

def diferenciar_serie(df,column):

```
for i in range (2,len(df)):
    df['diferencia'][i]=df[column][i]-df[column][i-1]
return df['diferencia']
```

When I run the code I get this error

> KeyError: 'diferencia'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception.

Something that makes my function work is that before running the function I use this code:
def diferenciar_serie(df,column):

```
for i in range (2,len(df)):
    df['diferencia']=df[column][i]-df[column][i-1]
return df['diferencia']
```

Basically the same code but without the positional argument [i] on the new column, this generates me a new column full of 0s, after running this code I run the code that first wasn't running and poof it now does work.

I want to optimize that process but I don't really know how, I mean I can't be running one code first and then the other in order to make my function work, if somebody knows how to fix this please help.

Comment: You need `df.diff(axis=1)` ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.